# how to get src attribute from an image using requests and beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get `src` attributes of images from a website. The problem is that it returns some encoded text instead of the `src`. The encoded text is:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhFQAXAPAAANba3wAAACwAAAAAFQAXAAACFISPqcvtD6OctNqLs968+w+GolUAADs=
```

The website is [here](https://www.redbubble.com/shop/shower-curtains/).

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.redbubble.com/shop/shower-curtains?page={}'
count = 0

for page in range(1,205):
    response = requests.get(url.format(page))
    if response.ok:
        contents = bs(response.text , 'lxml')

        curtains = contents.find_all('a' , class_='styles__link--2sYi3')
        for curtain in curtains:

            count += 1
            name = curtain.find('span' , class_='styles__text--NLf2i styles__display6--uq_8G styles__block--3OueG').text.strip()
            price = curtain.find('span' , class_='styles__text--NLf2i styles__body--3bpp7 styles__block--3OueG').text.strip()

            image_url = curtain.find('img' , class_='styles__image--2CwxX styles__productImage--3ZNPD styles__rounded--1lyoH styles__fluid--3dxe-').get('src')

            print('*'*20 , count , '*'*20)
            print('Name: {}'.format(name))
            print('Price: {}'.format(price))
            print('Image Url: {}'.format(image_url))
```

How can i get the `src` attribute from an image, like this one:

```
https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.887440492.3733/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1u2.jpg
```

Every page contains above 100 images of products. The first 16 returns valid `src` link, while the rest return encoded text like the above one.

Comment: _The problem is that it returns some encoded text instead of the `src`._ ...... _How can i get the `src` attribute from an image_ What you have **is** the value of the `src` attribute.

Comment: A few other things: The method used to select/find the elements looks brittle. Also, notice that all the img tags which don't have a URL in the `src` attribute have the **exact same** value? (`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhFQAXAPAAANba3wAAACwAAAAAFQAXAAACFISPqcvtD6OctNqLs968+w+GolUAADs=`)

Comment: @AMC all the src attributes have the url of the image,,,, it is just encoded into base64.

Comment: Hmm, I must have misread the values, I’ll double check tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from prettytable import PrettyTable

site = "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.{}/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg"

p = PrettyTable()
p.field_names = ["Name", "Price", "Url"]


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.select("img[class*=styles__rounded--1lyoH]")
    imgs = [img.group(1) for img in re.finditer(r'\.(\d+\.\d{4})', r.text)]
    goal = list(dict.fromkeys(imgs))
    for tar, go in zip(target, goal):
        p.add_row([tar['alt'], tar.find_all_next(
            "span")[3].text, site.format(go)])
    print(p)


main("https://www.redbubble.com/shop/shower-curtains/")
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     Name                                                                     |  Price  |                                              Url                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                              SOS Shower Curtain                                                              |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1163488491.7606/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       RETRO geometry 10 Shower Curtain                                                       |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1157791579.0857/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    Sphynx cat door knocker Shower Curtain                                                    |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1164112971.2614/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                              VHS Shower Curtain                                                              |  $56.76 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1166469289.0717/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                             Excuse Me, I'm Lost // Laid Back Edit Shower Curtain                                             |  $52.22 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.659833984.4609/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Easy Tiger Shower Curtain                                                           |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1094007186.3556/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       MANEKI WASH BLUE Shower Curtain                                                        |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.867564975.4912/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                        The Heart Of My Heart // So Far From Home Edit Shower Curtain                                         |  $52.22 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.439063572.6873/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       Blue Ocean Waves  Shower Curtain                                                       |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.525733200.2528/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                           Candy Sky Shower Curtain                                                           |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.906197994.7386/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     The Great Wave of Pug Shower Curtain                                                     |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.418461538.4822/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Cowboy Cats Shower Curtain                                                          |  $52.22 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.966660248.9573/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       Nine of Pentacles Shower Curtain                                                       | $113.53 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.880070297.7728/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        Moon River Lady Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.51953218.0964/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg  |
|                                                       Calming Mountain Shower Curtain                                                        |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.353536208.3857/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       Greympressionism Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.402792160.6730/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          The Birches Shower Curtain                                                          |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.887440492.3733/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|              Preppy brushstroke free polka dots black and white spots dots dalmation animal spots design minimal Shower Curtain              |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.60325696.5649/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg  |
|                                                      FANTASTIC BOTANICAL Shower Curtain                                                      |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.431602480.0359/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                       Geometric Compilation in Rose Gold and Blush Pink Shower Curtain                                       |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1115530718.0994/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                            Octopus Shower Curtain                                                            |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.854031637.1962/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        Suspicious Cats Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.815755503.6406/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Cuttlefish Shower Curtain                                                           |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.843986335.8355/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                Aurora borealis over mountains Shower Curtain                                                 |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1023977170.6148/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    A Wilderness Somewhere Shower Curtain                                                     |  $52.22 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.659807212.6173/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     A Dreamful Existence Shower Curtain                                                      |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.850078450.1026/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         BANANA - JADE Shower Curtain                                                         |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.485723302.7026/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                            Louisa Shower Curtain                                                             |  $58.12 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.714003984.1120/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                      Hookipa Surf Sunset Shower Curtain                                                      |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.499375997.7022/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                             Bison Shower Curtain                                                             |  $55.85 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.42365114.0077/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg  |
|                                                  Pigeons Doing Pigeon Things Shower Curtain                                                  |  $61.30 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.458114091.1359/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                              Wolves of the World (Green pattern) Shower Curtain                                              |  $53.58 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.841240259.3936/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     The Birches (in Blue) Shower Curtain                                                     |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.364684526.2726/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                            Sapphire & Jade Stained Glass Mandalas Shower Curtain                                             |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.855827011.8684/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    The Ricks Must Be Crazy Shower Curtain                                                    |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.843212193.9827/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                               Retro Eames-Era Atomic Inspired 3 Shower Curtain                                               |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.378399040.6864/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                           Retro Color Block Popsicle Sticks Orange  Shower Curtain                                           |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.923368972.5303/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     Blue Zoomies pattern Shower Curtain                                                      |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.843634928.4840/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       MANEKI WASH GREEN Shower Curtain                                                       |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.867566785.4956/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                   Soft Blue Gradient Cubes Shower Curtain                                                    |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.444412654.7790/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Ocean Crash Shower Curtain                                                          |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1168238045.2369/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        Birds Of Jungle Shower Curtain                                                        |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.847435442.1963/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     A Fox in the Wild... Shower Curtain                                                      |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1165884463.6125/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       Gold palm leaves Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.409101292.3761/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        Octopsychedelia Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.53004778.7977/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg  |
|                                                        Skeletor's Cat Shower Curtain                                                         |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.895512143.8793/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                Palm Leaves In Black And White Shower Curtain                                                 |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.519484923.2210/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                           Star Lake Shower Curtain                                                           |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.871944713.8979/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         Sloth Stripe Shower Curtain                                                          |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.205710146.7038/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                   Aurelia Goldfish Mermaid Shower Curtain                                                    |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.865016799.8085/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                           The Beast Shower Curtain                                                           |  $54.95 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.362724938.7654/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                            Leopard Print - Silver Gray and White  Shower Curtain                                             |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.793900103.0668/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    Blue Valmalenco, Italy Shower Curtain                                                     |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.742174200.0519/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         Hanging Orbs Shower Curtain                                                          |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.259468032.1028/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     Vintage Mermaid Paris Shower Curtain                                                     |  $90.82 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.841953455.5675/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     Construction Trucks  Shower Curtain                                                      |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.849779994.3406/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                   Cut + Paste Lemon Pattern Shower Curtain                                                   |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1010390743.9556/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                             Sloth Shower Curtain                                                             |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.956486764.4016/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                             Abstract Multi Color Cubizm Painting Shower Curtain                                              |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.461755006.7432/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Jelly beans Shower Curtain                                                          |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.724354274.0522/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         Lost in Space Shower Curtain                                                         |  $54.95 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.876423644.5372/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       When Legends Meet Shower Curtain                                                       |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1118539670.1106/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                  Selfie Giraffe in New York Shower Curtain                                                   |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.858065257.9299/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Biology 101 Shower Curtain                                                          |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.669396941.9765/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                            Popoki Shower Curtain                                                             |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.385662285.0930/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                           Be Pride Shower Curtain                                                            |  $55.40 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1152655614.6796/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    Each Moment of the Year Shower Curtain                                                    |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.809122096.7854/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         The Immortal Shower Curtain                                                          |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.914928995.9187/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                 Pink And Grey Gradient Cubes Shower Curtain                                                  |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.382851966.5829/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                             It Seemed To Chase the Darkness Away Shower Curtain                                              |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.809110090.7036/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                          Morty "I Do As The Crystal Guides" quote from Rick and Morty™ Death Crystal Shower Curtain                          |  $52.45 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.966553275.3415/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                          Eames Era Starbursts and Globes 3 (bkgrnd) Shower Curtain                                           |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.375387600.7328/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     Boho Flowers Pattern Shower Curtain                                                      |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.935336830.2227/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                Henri Matisse - Blue Nude 1952 - Original Artwork Reproduction Shower Curtain                                 |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.672148845.0063/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                 Gold Indigo Malachite Marble Shower Curtain                                                  |  $65.84 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.862235612.8174/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                  Death Head Moth Witch Board Shower Curtain                                                  |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.959173541.8347/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                               Leopard Gray and Light Gray Print Shower Curtain                                               |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.851441807.9725/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
| The Dunder Office Mifflin Inc. Design, T-Shirt, tshirt, tee, jersey, poster, Original Funny Gift Idea, Dwight Best Quote From Shower Curtain |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.636556380.5281/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                Vintage Solar System Map (1883) Shower Curtain                                                |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.854873138.6748/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         Flower Field Shower Curtain                                                          |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.843342485.3106/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                      Terrazzo Sun Light Shower Curtain                                                       |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.863871946.0983/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                       Stylish Gold Diamond Shapes Doodles White Pattern Shower Curtain                                       |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.954706178.4364/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                       Brown Sideways Stripes - Mudcloth Tribal Pattern Shower Curtain                                        |  $50.50 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1103752861.2180/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       Rainbow Pineapple Shower Curtain                                                       |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.860968450.0931/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                Joan Miro The Sun (El Sol) 1949 Painting Artwork For Prints Posters Tshirts Bags Women Men Kids Shower Curtain                |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.845987820.3095/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                  Rose gold copper honeycomb Shower Curtain                                                   |  $74.93 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.407963990.2008/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                            Burlap Shower Curtain                                                             |  $58.12 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.864516329.6111/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    Vintage poster - Japan Shower Curtain                                                     |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.435051155.2108/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                  Wolf Howling At The Moon / Wolf Moon Night Sky Stars Space Shower Curtain                                   |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.933994845.0668/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                   Sea angel & sea butterfly Shower Curtain                                                   |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.716190832.3677/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        Terrazzo matrix Shower Curtain                                                        |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.866500337.9787/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        Spring Skull 2 Shower Curtain                                                         |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.910650710.4621/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Rainy Days Shower Curtain                                                           |  $77.20 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.928689192.5441/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                  geometric shapes abstract 2 Shower Curtain                                                  |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.944849646.3366/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                     Having meals together Shower Curtain                                                     |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.944958024.7422/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    Bookworm Antique books Shower Curtain                                                     |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.975316466.8634/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                               Tyrannosaurus Rex in Cat Jammies Shower Curtain                                                |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1151176630.8339/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                   Le ballet des carpes koi Shower Curtain                                                    |  $59.03 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.437377350.5294/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                       Hammerhead Shark Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.981964804.1345/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                         Rose Garden V Shower Curtain                                                         |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1062192717.5743/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                        shibes in cream Shower Curtain                                                        |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.372197220.3650/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                    La Boheme Teal Floral  Shower Curtain                                                     |  $56.76 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.855648772.5890/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Eucalyptus Shower Curtain                                                           |  $54.49 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1077181042.7318/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                      Blue Iris Blossoms Shower Curtain                                                       |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.817250422.7343/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                            Jurassic Portal | Retro Rainbow Palette | Dinosaur Science Fiction Art Shower Curtain                             |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.932524721.5266/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                           Forelsket Shower Curtain                                                           |  $56.76 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1077768659.7113/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                          Hamnoy Hut Shower Curtain                                                           |  $56.76 | https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1011615092.6091/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
|                                                By The Shore By Colleen Ranney Shower Curtain                                                 |  $54.49 |  https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.992576471.2172/ur,shower_curtain_closed,square,600x600.1.jpg |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is that program doing?

Comment: @AMC the website which the `OP` mentioned is using a `JS` function which automatically encode the `src` url with `base64` once you make a get request while you parse the `source` code. so the code is actually picking up the `img` `id` from the `meta` tag and assign it to the complete `url`

Comment: And yet again.. You are awesome... sir

Comment: but plz plz plz,, i have problems in pagination if you can help me with that. thankss in advance

Comment: i have updated the code for pagination. it works well for the first 100 pages and then it just repeat the same 100 again.

Comment: @AhmadFaraz that's will be an `off-topic` for that question. you've to open a separate question and limit your question to specific issue.